# sign in by twitter and users verifier, Net::Twitter::Role::OAuth

Tags: perl, twitter, oauth

Having a Twitter APP and a user signing in using a website and that app. We received the “oauth_verifier” for that user.
After signing in, the user should follow our Twitter account by default. 
Achieving this, I used the 1st example in Net::Twitter::Role::OAuth.

Our “consumer_key” and “consumer_secret”, and

```
my($access_token, $access_token_secret, $user_id, $screen_name) = $nt->request_access_token(verifier => $verifier)
```

I cannot go further, getting a 401 error from Twitter:

```
auth_url => https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=rhDMIgAAAAAA0FiXAAABW17hoRI
Net::Twitter::Role::OAuth::request_access_token(): GET https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token failed: 401 Authorization Required at login.pl line xx
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If your app is a Mojo app, you could just use a plugin for this. https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::Web::Auth

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from your question if you're trying to do PIN-Based or 3-Legged OAuth.

In PIN-Based OAuth, you first redirect the user to the authorization URL:

```
use Net::Twitter;

my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(
    traits          => ['API::RESTv1_1', 'OAuth'],
    consumer_key    => "YOUR-CONSUMER-KEY",
    consumer_secret => "YOUR-CONSUMER-SECRET",
);

my $url = $nt->get_authorization_url();

print "Location: ", $url, "\n\n";
```

After signing in, the user receives a PIN number that must be passed as the verifier parameter to get the access token:

```
my $pin = 'PIN-NUMBER-PROVIDED-AFTER-LOGIN';

my($access_token, $access_token_secret, $user_id, $screen_name) = $nt->request_access_token(verifier => $pin);
```

In 3-Legged OAuth, you start almost in the same way, except that you must specify a callback URL (the same that you registered for your app) when calling "get_authorization_url":

```
use Net::Twitter;

my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(
    traits          => ['API::RESTv1_1', 'OAuth'],
    consumer_key    => "YOUR-CONSUMER-KEY",
    consumer_secret => "YOUR-CONSUMER-SECRET",
);

my $url = $nt->get_authorization_url(callback => 'MY-CALLBACK-URL');

print "Location: ", $url, "\n\n";
```

This time, after signing in, instead of giving the user a PIN number, Twitter automatically redirects to your callback URL passing two query string parameters: oauth_token and oauth_verifier, which you should use as key/secret request token to get the access token:

```
use Net::Twitter;
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;

my $oauth_token = $cgi->param('oauth_token');
my $oauth_verifier = $cgi->param('oauth_verifier');

my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(
    traits          => ['API::RESTv1_1', 'OAuth'],
    consumer_key    => "YOUR-CONSUMER-KEY",
    consumer_secret => "YOUR-CONSUMER-SECRET",
);

$nt->request_token($oauth_token);
$nt->request_token_secret($oauth_verifier);

my($access_token, $access_token_secret, $user_id, $screen_name) = $nt->request_access_token(verifier => $oauth_verifier);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You correctly describe the oauth process with Twitter -- but this merely authenticates and grants access.  What calls do you do to actually get the firstname, lastname, and email address with $nt?

Comment: Yes, this merely authenticates and grants access, which is exactly what the original question was asking for help. The next step would be something like:

Comment: `my $resp = $nt->verify_credentials({include_email => 1 });`

Comment: Then you could get what you want, like $resp->{'name'} and $resp->{'email'}